# How to drop flow files in a processor in nifi 1.7 using rest api or cli?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have tried using following Http url using post method

```
https://{host-name}/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/{id}/drop-requests
```

Web browser responded:

> HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

It seems like Nifi 1.7 is not supported to drop-requests using above method. Is there some other way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in http the methods are the following: `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc

`https://{host-name}/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/{id}/drop-requests` - is an url

The error `Method Not Allowed` means you are not providing a correct method for this url

to see correct method look into [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html)

[image]

---

Or use `your browser > devtools (F12) > network` in nifi page

clean the required queue and see captured rest request in `devtools`